# onCreate() and onCreateView() invokes a lot more than required (Fragments)

Tags: android

Can somebody explain why the `onCreate()` and `onCreateView()` are being invoked so many times which increments with each orientation change?

Here is very simple app which consists of one `Activity` composed of two `Fragments`. The second `Fragment` loads **dynamically**. If you define these two `Fragments` in `main.xml` there would not be such a behavior.

Here is `main.xml`:

```
       <fragment class="ets.saeref.Left"
        android:id="@+id/left_frag"
        android:layout_weight="70"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

     <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/right_frag" 
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is left frag:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#000000">
    <Button android:text="Landscape" android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is right frag:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#ffffff">
    <Button android:text="Landscape" android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Left.class:

```
public class Left extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("Left", "onCreate()");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("Left", "onCreateView()");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.left, container, false);
    }
}
```

Right.class:

```
public class Right extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("Right", "onCreate()");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("Right", "onCreateView()");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.right, container, false);
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Fragment fg = new Right();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.right_frag, fg)
            .commit();
        Log.i("Main", "onCreate()");
    }
}
```

Log after several orientation changes:

```
08-28 21:47:38.220: INFO/Main(1099): onCreate()
08-28 21:47:38.220: INFO/Right(1099): onCreateView()
08-28 21:47:38.220: INFO/Right(1099): onCreateView()
08-28 21:47:38.220: INFO/Right(1099): onCreateView()
08-28 21:47:38.220: INFO/Right(1099): onCreate()
08-28 21:47:38.220: INFO/Right(1099): onCreateView()
08-28 21:47:41.110: INFO/ActivityManager(142): Config changed: {1.0 0mcc0mnc en_US sw800dp w1280dp h752dp xlrg land finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.162}
08-28 21:47:41.140: INFO/Right(1099): onCreate()
08-28 21:47:41.140: INFO/Right(1099): onCreate()
08-28 21:47:41.140: INFO/Right(1099): onCreate()
08-28 21:47:41.140: INFO/Right(1099): onCreate()
08-28 21:47:41.170: INFO/Left(1099): onCreate()
08-28 21:47:41.170: INFO/Left(1099): onCreateView()
08-28 21:47:41.170: INFO/Main(1099): onCreate()
08-28 21:47:41.170: INFO/Right(1099): onCreateView()
08-28 21:47:41.170: INFO/Right(1099): onCreateView()
08-28 21:47:41.170: INFO/Right(1099): onCreateView()
08-28 21:47:41.170: INFO/Right(1099): onCreateView()
08-28 21:47:41.190: INFO/Right(1099): onCreate()
08-28 21:47:41.190: INFO/Right(1099): onCreateView()
08-28 21:47:45.070: INFO/ActivityManager(142): Config changed: {1.0 0mcc0mnc en_US sw800dp w800dp h1232dp xlrg port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.163}
08-28 21:47:45.120: INFO/Right(1099): onCreate()
08-28 21:47:45.120: INFO/Right(1099): onCreate()
08-28 21:47:45.120: INFO/Right(1099): onCreate()
08-28 21:47:45.120: INFO/Right(1099): onCreate()
08-28 21:47:45.120: INFO/Right(1099): onCreate()
08-28 21:47:45.130: INFO/Left(1099): onCreate()
08-28 21:47:45.130: INFO/Left(1099): onCreateView()
08-28 21:47:45.130: INFO/Main(1099): onCreate()
08-28 21:47:45.130: INFO/Right(1099): onCreateView()
08-28 21:47:45.130: INFO/Right(1099): onCreateView()
08-28 21:47:45.130: INFO/Right(1099): onCreateView()
08-28 21:47:45.140: INFO/Right(1099): onCreateView()
08-28 21:47:45.140: INFO/Right(1099): onCreateView()
08-28 21:47:45.140: INFO/Right(1099): onCreate()
08-28 21:47:45.140: INFO/Right(1099): onCreateView()
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I can't point to the documentation which explains this, but the solution is to only create and add the fragment when the activity first loads, like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Fragment fg = new Right();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.right_frag, fg)
            .commit();
    }
    Log.i("Main", "onCreate()");
}
```

Comment: Please point to the documentation if you would found. Thanks.

Comment: There are examples in the ApiDocs that do it, but as far as I know it isn't explained in the actual documentation.

Comment: The most formal documentation I've found on this is the following example: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#AddAtRuntime

Answer (score 13):

Yes, this is very bad documented. The explanation is that when the `Activity` is `restored` it will "auto-magically" `restore` the `Fragments` that were added in it, so `adding` another `Fragment` in your `Activity` will basically add another new `Fragment` on top of the previous `Fragment\s` that are actually `restored` by `Android`.

This behavior is definitely intended, and the approach suggested by @Joris Wit is the correct one.

Also this is very helpful when you think about it, because let's say you have a stack of `Fragments` added one on top of each other, and you can navigate back to them using the `back` key. In the case of a rotation, if `Android` would not restore the backstack of `Fragments` you will lose all of them, or you will have to implement some mechanism to keep track of your `Fragment` `stack`.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't use different layouts for different orientations, I think that you should use `android:configChanges="orientation"` in your manifest.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

Comment: This is very wise! Thank you for pointing this out. As I prefer when things are said clearly: Actually you have to use `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` as attribute to the related activity's `<activity>` tag in your manifest.

Comment: Yet, this practice is not recommended and `"should be avoided and used only as a last resort."` This is one of the first thing we can read when we click on your link.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have so many fragments there!
If you define fragment in xml file you **can not** define "it" again in your code!
There are two ways how to define fragmets: **dynamiclly** (in your code) and **statically** (in your xml)!
Take a look here:
http://marakana.com/s/post/1250/android_fragments_tutorial

It is really good tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

An orientation change causes the system to go through the process of saving instance state, pausing, stopping, destroying, and then creating a new instance of the activity with the saved state. So this is the reason why there is so much onCreate and onCreateView calls.

I do not think the `if (savedInstanceState == null)` condition in the `onCreate` method is a good idea; the state-saving mechanism will not work properly...

Answer (score -1):

main class should extend FragmentActivity and not Activity.

also look up Activity life cycle on the android doc